# Add filter based on condition in MongDB

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am new to MongoDB and I have a collection **student**. I need to add the **student.name** filter in the query only when **is_rep=true**.

My document structure.

```
{
  {
    "student": {
      "name": "arun",
      "dept": "bio",
      "subject": "bot"
    },
    "is_rep": true
  },
  {
    "student": {
      "name": "div",
      "dept": "csc",
      "subject": "program"
    },
    "is_rep": false
  }
}
```

Can anyone please guide me to achieve this in pymongo

Comment: Can you add your query too? So we can answer based on the rest of the structure.

Comment: IS that possible you to convert the query to pymongo if I give you mongo script ?

Comment: @varman yeah sure.

Comment: @Dinesh I have added the answer

Comment: @TusharShahi I couldn't frame the query correctly. Tried to use $cond but no luck

Comment: @Dinesh does the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregations like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      is_rep: true,
      "student.name": "arun"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aw7u5pAHDKz)**

Or you can use find query

```
db.collection.find({
  is_rep: true,
  "student.name": "arun"
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wNYrJ0DkQGe)**